# End Process in Powershell with absolutely no output

Tags: powershell

I have a script which does some settings in registry. As a consequence I have to kill one process.

```
Stop-Process -processname explorer -force | Out-Null
```

Now I would like to get rid of this message:

```
Der Vorgang wurde erfolgreich beendet.
```

(I guess english version must be something like: `The process was completed successfully`) Do you have any idea how to stop all output of `Stop-Process`?

**#Update**
You are very right I should have tried just that command alone to see it is not the  right command to look at. I structured my console output better to find out what command is causing me that trouble and found out these two:

```
reg add "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop" /v Wallpaper /t REG_SZ /d C:\folder\wallpaper.png /f
reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Power" /v HiberbootEnabled /t reg_dword /d 0 /f
```

Append these two with `| Out-Null`  works just as expected. :)

I guess I was confused by the message "The process was completed successfully" because I would not expect it after editing registry. In my script I use also other methods to change registry and they do not produce that output. For example:

```
Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Explorer" -Name "DisableNotificationCenter" -Type DWord -Value 1
```

And since I had this message appear two times and I was killing two processes in my script I was wrong assuming that Stop-Process is at fault. Yet another example how easy it is to draw wrong correlations. Thanks for Help. I can't grasp how could I miss it.

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce the behavior described, what version of PowerShell are you using (see `$PSVersionTable.PSVersion`), and which version of Windows?

Comment: I also cant reproduce it...usually there is no output on this command...I tried `stop-Process -name iexplore` and just closed IExplorer...`-force` or `|Out-Null` was not necessary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that you are trying to suppress the right thing? This is a typical message of
[reg](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/reg) command, which is probably used in your script considering it does some settings in the registry. `Out-Null` that instead of `Stop-Process`.